# Standard conjecture on u-invariants?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, quadratic-forms, number-fields

This is well beyond my expertise, but I just learned some of the history behind
$u$-invariants of fields $F$,
where ($u(F)+1$)-variable quadratic equations always have a non-trivial solution,
but $u(F)$-variable equations may not.
Here is [the Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-invariant).
In particular, although it seemed possible that the $u$-invariant of any field was
a power of $2$, it was shown by Merkurev in 1991 that there is a field
with $u$-invariant of any even number. But the hypothesis that it could never
be an odd number was contradicted by Izhboldin (in [Fields of $u$-invariant $9$](https://doi.org/10.2307/3062141)) in 2001 who constructed a field with $u$-invariant of $9$.<sup>1</sup>

> ***Q***. My question is: Where does this issue stand now, ~20 years later?
> Is there some sense
> among experts that there is a field with $u$-invariant for any odd number larger than $7$?
> Or is it completely open, with no prevailing hypothesis?

As FZaldivar pointed out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377381/standard-conjecture-on-u-invariants#comment957289_377381), it was earlier known
that $u \neq 3,5,7$, so $u=9$ was the first realized odd number.

---

<sup>1</sup>
"Oleg Izhboldin died tragically ... at the age of 37 after submitting this article"
[ZBL review](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0998.11015).

Comment: According to the review you link to, "It is not difficult to show that $u\neq 3,5,7$"

Comment: @FZaldivar: Oh, I see. Yes, that came prior to $u=9$. I will edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: T. Y. Lam calls these three cases a "folklore result" and proves them in Propositions 6.8 and 6.9 of his book " Introduction to quadratic forms over fields" (AMS, 2005).. He also remarks that these cases were known before Merkurev's work. Your question is quite interesting.

Comment: A. Vishik has constructed fields with $u$-invariant $2^r+1$ for every $r\geq 3$;  see: <a href="https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1236.11037">zbm</a>

Comment: The ZBM link @FZaldivar [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377381/standard-conjecture-on-u-invariants#comment957297_377381):  [Vishik - Fields of $u$-invariant $2^r + 1$](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1236.11037) ([link to article](https://doi-.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4747-6_22)).

Comment: @LSpice: Typo in your link. Here it is: [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4747-6_22).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, thanks!  Fortunately this sequence of fixed-up links seems to have converged.  :-)

Comment: @FZaldivar: I added the Vishik result to Wikipedia, filling that lacuna. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the classical $u$-invariant of fields of characteristic $\neq 2$, some known results are:

1. The $u$-invariant of formally real fields is $\infty$.
2. If $K$ is an algebraically closed field, its $u$-invariant is $1$. More generally, if $K$ does not have quadratic extensions its $u$-invariant is $1$.
3. There are no fields of $u$-invariant $3, 5$ or $7$. This was proven by R. Elman, T. Y. Lam, (  Math. Z. 131 (1973), 283--304  and Invent. Math. 21 (1973), 125--137.)
4. There are fields of any even $u$-invariant (A. S. Merkurev, Izv. Akad. Nauk. SSSR Ser. Mat. 55 (1991) No. 1, 218--224.)
5. There is a field of $u$-invariant $9$ (O. T. Izhboldin, Ann. of Math. (2) 154 (2001), no. 3, 529--587)
6. There is a field of $u$-invariant $2^r+1$ for every integer $r\geq 3$ (A. Vishnik, Algebra, arithmetic, and geometry: in honor of Yu. I. Manin. Vol. II, 661--685,
   Progr. Math., 270, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 2009.)

On the other hand, for certain families of fields, the $u$-invariant is known, and for other families, the computations are not complete. For example, if $F$ is a finite field of odd characteristic by the Chevalley-Waring theorem every quadratic form in three variables over $F$ represents $0$, that is, every $3$-dimensional form over $F$ is isotropic and thus $u(F)=2$.